# Sorting GridView on Another page as sorted on a previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my application.
On click of a button, same grid with same columns is also loaded in another page.
Now what I want to do is if user has sorted the grid with some column on 1sr page, grid on another page which loads on click of button should also be sorted with same column which user has selected on previous page.
How can I achieve this.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated... :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use a session variable to store the sort direction. So, when you are loading the GridView you ask for the session variable in order to sort it properly.

It should be something similar to this:

```
private string getSortDirectionString()
    {
        if (Session["sortDirection"] == null)
        {
            Session["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["sortDirection"].ToString() == "ASC")
            {
                Session["sortDirection"] = "DESC";
                return Session["sortDirection"].ToString();
            }
            if (Session["sortDirection"].ToString() == "DESC")
            {
                Session["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
                return Session["sortDirection"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return Session["sortDirection"].ToString();
    }
```

And this is how you should sort your GridView:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        listBind(); //procedure to populate your GridView
        DataSet dsSortTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataSet;
        DataTable dtSortTable = dsSortTable.Tables[0];
        if (dtSortTable != null)
        {
            DataView dvSortedView = new DataView(dtSortTable);
            dvSortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + getSortDirectionString();
            Session["sortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
            GridView1.DataSource = dvSortedView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

In this way you'll always have the sortExpression stored in the session variable and you could use it across the whole app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a rough outline you could -

- Write a value to a hidden field when the sort param of the first grid
  is changed
- Pick up the parameter when moving to the second page and append it to
  the querystring
- On the second page retreive the parameter form the querysting and
  sort the grid accordingly